# PyCharm: autocomplete on "self...." does not work since with_metaclass() gets used

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pycharm, metaclass

Since we use [with_metaclass()](https://python-future.org/reference.html#future.utils.with_metaclass) PyCharm does not detect the super-class any more.

New code (autocomplete does not work):

```
class EditTestCase(with_metaclass(EditTestCaseMeta, EditTestCaseMixin, unittest.TestCase)):
    ....
```

Old code (autocomplete worked):

```
class EditTestCase(EditTestCaseMixin, unittest.TestCase):
    __metaclass__ = EditTestCaseMeta
    ....
```

Code needs to support Python2.7 and Python3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `with_metaclass()` from [six](https://six.readthedocs.io/index.html#six.with_metaclass) module is working for Python2 and 3.

Comment: Great. Now PyCharm detects the parent classes and autocomplete works again. Thank you very much for this hint!